# Is basic authentication the right choice?

Tags: javascript, java, security, dropwizard

I have been using Dropwizard to develop a RESTful backend for my webapp. Now, developing the frontend, I need to log users in. I have been using the @Auth annotation, e.g:

```
@POST
public void createEvent(@Auth User user, @FormParam("startTime") @NotNull @Min(0) Long startTime,
                        @FormParam("endTime") @NotNull @Min(0) Long endTime) {
    validateEvent(startTime, endTime);
    eventDAO.insertEvent(new Event(Util.convertMillisToDate(startTime), Util.convertMillisToDate(endTime), user.getName()));
}
```

to ensure that the user is logged in. All is fine and well, but this is using http basic authentication. The consequence is that I have to send the username and password to the server every time I want to do an action. This begs the question: How am I supposed to store the password on the client? Should I be hashing the passwords on the client (perhaps together with its salt?) so that if I store them in e.g. a cookie, it's not plaintext to people who could access the computer? Should I have been using user access tokens all along?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using some sort of session tokens is almost always the best choice. You only have to send the username and password once, and then you get a session token back that you use to identify the user in all other requests.

There's a number of advantages here:

1. You won't need to store the password on the client, only the session token.
2. If a session gets compromised (e.g., by a rogue client), you can just invalidate the token, you don't have to also change the password.
3. You can restrict permissions for a specific token.
4. You can let users generate tokens for third-party apps without giving these apps the password.

Points 1-2 are nice in any system, because they make sessions more secure in general. Points 2-4 are especially useful when you're designing public APIs, because you can use protocols like [OAuth 2.0](https://oauth.net/2/) to give third-party applications secure and revocable access to all or parts of your application, without having to give away usernames or passwords to that third party.

Comment: So esentially store a username->user_token relation with some lifetime?

Comment: @Amnestic Yes, that's basically it.

Comment: @Amnestic You also want to make sure that the tokens are long and randomly generated (if possible, preferably with cryptographic randomness) so that people can't just guess them to get access to a user.

Comment: I just want to add to other people doing this, that DropWizard has a OAuth2 authentication filter. You can use that to use for any session key, which allows you to keep using @Auth on your methods.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I would suggest you to use AUTH 2 authentication system.

1. Important thing here is Hashing is not encryption and added to that Even stored cookies can be accessed.
2. With use of tokens, you allow users to login using their account with third party applications, and ease the pain.

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated, tokens are great since you can have control over them, revoke if needed, etc. You only should store the token client side. If storing passwords in a server Db, they should still be salted in case the Db is compromised.

Just understand the difference between JWTs and other opaque tokens and mechanisms. JWTS store information directly in the token and is signed (although not encrypted) so you don't store personally identifiable information, rather a user_id or similar.

I wrote a security related blog post on various token types, using Cookies vs Local Storage, etc.
https://www.moesif.com/blog/technical/restful-apis/Authorization-on-RESTful-APIs/

Also, take a look at https://jwt.io/introduction. It gives an overview of how JWTs work. (I have no affiliation with Auth0 BTW, but we use them for our company, Moesif).